# Attach a word document to an e-mail and send without saving locally in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an app that creates a word document, and I need to send it out without saving it locally. In other words, I need to send out an object. I know the code below doesn't work because my document is an object. Is there any way to do this?

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Document found

Does anyone know how to do this? Here is what I have:

```
def document_writer():
document = Document()
document.add_heading('Sample Document', 0)
document.add_paragraph("fsfsa")

document.add_heading('Addresses', 2)


return document

def mailsend(send_from, send_to, subject, text, login, password, document, files=None,
          smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = send_to
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(document, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="crap.docx"')
msg.attach(part)
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
server.starttls()
#server.starttls()
server.login(login, password)
server.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())

server.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

at some point in your code a function expects a `string` but gets a `Document` class which python then does not know how to convert to a `string`.

In your function `document_writer` you are creating such a class `Document`
So you should check where such created `Document` ojects are used.

To then solve this Problem there could be three solutions:

1. This `Document` Class can be converted to a string. Then you can just do `str(Document)`
2. This Document Class can not be converted to a string via `str()` but has a special function to do this. Then you can just do `document_variable.convert_to_str_function()`
3. You are able to save this `Document` Class to disk as a file. Then you should have a look at those answers: [Binary file email attachment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798470/binary-file-email-attachment-problem) to send a disk based file via email